# NSMutable dictionary, do I initialise every time it is used or save and load it to file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, nskeyedarchiver

I have a class that uses a `NSMutableDictionary`. This dictionary contains between 40-60 objects of a custom class "appStrings". Right now every time I used the class I just init the dictionary calling my initDictionary method and this adds all the objects and keys. Is it better/faster to instead init the `NSDictionary` once and save it to file using `NSKeyedArchiver` or just call the init method each time? In terms of writing code it makes no difference, I have to init the dictionary at some point even if I save it and never init again. But what about in terms of performance?

edit: example of an object

```
appMessage *a= [[miaoMEMessage alloc] initWithCode:@"a" replies: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"j", @"k", nil] english:@"Hi!" andChineseTrad:@"嗨!"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general is always faster to create object then loading them from disk.
In your example is faster to create the dictionary in code then loading it from disk (it will have to create the same objects **and** load from disk).

Comment: The dictionary is stored in a property after it is init. However the object is only created when it's needed, for a few of the view controllers I am using.

Comment: then if you don't have any heavy code that creates the dictionary content it's faster to create it in code then loading it from disk, but my guess is that you won't notice any difference in the app if the dictionary contents are lightweight

Comment: What's classed as heavy code? I have edited my question with an example of the objects I am using. Just objects that contain 3 NSStrings and an NSArray. The dictionary will have around 40-60 of these.

Comment: Something that takes long computational time like looping through long array. Based on the example it's faster to create it in the code and also less code to deal with!

Comment: Okay, I won't archive it then. thanks for your answer